# How to pass class object from one screen to another without using global store in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Cognito SDK and while implementing the login flow, getting the following warning

```
Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state
```

The login flow consists of two screens

1. Login screen where a user would enter his registered email id
2. OTP screen where the user would fill the OTP received via Email

The above warning occurs when I pass the Cognito user (a class object from Cognito SDK) from Login screen to OTP screen, this object needs to passed from Login screen to OTP screen because the `sendCustomChallengeAnswer` needs that user object in order to verify the OTP entered by the user.

Though the react-navigation library recommends using a global store to pass complex data from one screen to another, I am not utilising any state management library such as redux.

Is there any other way to pass such objects from one screen to another screen?

Comment: how do you pass it right now in your code? what's your `Linking Options` looks like?

Comment: I'm just simply passing the objec in the navigate function as normal params, due to which I'm getting the warning

Comment: ah okay, yea I get it now. Yea, I don't think I have any other idea aside from `Context`. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to store the information at the root of the component